# Sunspot - Search multiple models using a conditional with call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot, sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr

```
class Cat < ActiveRecord::Base
  searchable do
    string :color
  end
end
class Dog < ActiveRecord::Base
  searchable do
    string :color
  end
end
```

Given the models `Cat` and `Dog` above, how do I do a sunspot search for All dogs + only cats that are brown.

```
|dogs|color|    |cats|color|
------------    ------------
| 1  |black|    | 1  |black|
| 2  |brown|    | 2  |brown|
| 3  | red |    | 3  | red |
```

With the above dogs/cats, I want `Dogs [1, 2 3]` and `Cat [2]`.

I want something like below, but condition the `with` to only apply to `Cats`.

```
Sunspot.search(Dog, Cat) do
  with :color, "brown"
end
```

**Is there a `with` parameter that is the model type?** If so I could do something like this:

```
Sunspot.search(Dog, Cat) do
  any_of do
    with :color, "brown"
    with :model, Dog
  end
end
```

**How do you scope the Sunspot DSL pieces around a model being searched for?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding a field `table_name` to the model index and used that.

```
class Dog < ActiveRecord::Base
  searchable do
    string :color
    string :table_name do Dog.table_name end
  end
end

Sunspot.search(Dog, Cat) do
  any_of do
    with :color, "brown"
    with :table_name, Dog.table_name
  end
end
```

Comment: If there is a better answer, I am open to that.